# how to display items of an rss reader

Tags: android, rss

I'm trying to make an rss app.I've managed to retrieve RSS feeds, store them to my custom collection(ArrayList) and display them on a listview.For that i'm using the setters/getters methods that i made in my "items" class.
Now each time that an item is selected on my list i want to load a new activity and display the selected rss post.I've used Serializable interface to pass the "ArrayList" to my new activity, but there my setters/getters are not accesible and i can't dispay the rss post.
So what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You said your created an items class. Create an Object of that in your Activity and retrieve the information from that class.